# Switching glassfish 2.x to 3.1.1

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

So i am managing an 'old' java project that is using glassfish 2.x.
Seems like netbeans does not support 2.x versions anymore, so i want to change it to 3.1.1.
How to properly make that change?
I have JDK 1.6 installed. When i try to select the 3.1.1 does not fix the error "Unable to find Application Server J2EE"

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this question is in the wrong place, this is really not my specialization.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

1. The GlassFish Server 2.x plugin is available in the netbeans update center, so you can continue to use the latest NetBeans with GlassFish 2.x.
2. Changing to 3.x can be a good idea  for various reasons (depends on the state of your deployment).  How you access GlassFish depends on which install you want to use.  The latest netbeans ships with GlassFish 3.1, and should work out of the box. To use a previously downloaded GlassFish 3.1.1 installation, you'll have to point to it in the NetBeans IDE by going to Tools->Servers->Add Server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The GF 3.1.1 was already added to Netbeans. The point is in *i guess* selecting the correct library in maven's pom.xml, so the project can run over the desired glassfish version.